# Adding XMP Metadata to my document

Tags: hyperxmp

besides the printed book an e-book version is planned and the publisher requires certain XMP metadata to be set for it. More specifically `Title`, `Author`, `Copyright-Status`, `Copyright-Notice` and `Copyright-URL`. For me personally I would like to store the git hash it was created from as well.

This is what I tried:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\immediate\write18{git log -1 --format="\@percentchar H " > currentVersionLong}

\usepackage{hyperxmp}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
    pdftitle={The title},
    pdfauthor={The author},
    pdfcopyright={\textcopyright\ 2020 by the publisher},
%   pdfversionid={\IfFileExists{currentVersionLong}{\input{currentVersionLong}}{No version information}},
    pdflicenseurl={https://tex.stackexchange.com}
}

\begin{document}
    Just an empty document
\end{document}
```

However there are two issues:

1. If I check the PDF in Adobe Reader, I can only see this information:
   [image]

[image]

Shouldn't I see the data here, or do I need to inspect the PDF file uncompressed in `Notepad++`?

2. I want to read the current git has from the command line writing it to a file through `write18`. However the line `pdfversionid={\IfFileExists{currentVersionLong}{\input{currentVersionLong}}{No version information}},` is not liked by hyperxmp. An idea how I can maybe read this into a macro first and then use it that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hyperxmp fills the so-call xmp-metadata. You can check them by looking in the pdf (normally they are uncompressed even if the rest of the pdf is compressed. They start with

```
<<
/Type /Metadata /Subtype /XML 
/Length 8178      
>>
stream
<?xpacket begin="ï»¿" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/">
  <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
    <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
....
```

The screenshots in your question show mainly the content of the Info dictionary (the adobe reader will also use values from the xmp metadata, so it could be a mix of both).
You can add more values there with the `pdfinfo` key:

```
\hypersetup{%
    pdftitle={The title},
    pdfauthor={The author},
    pdfinfo={Copyright=some copyright info, 
            licence=https://tex.stackexchange.com}
}
```

would give

[image]

You can use the catchfile package to catch some file content inside a macro and then use in the metadata.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my investigation showed however that starting from a certain file size, the XMP gets compressed, too. This is why I overlooked the XMP at first, it was in my file, but I couldn't see it through Notepad++ or Adobe Reader. This is the next catch, the actual XMP data can not be viewed through Adobe Reader, you need Adobe Acrobat DC at least to have the `Additional Metadata...` button in the description.
The additional `pdfinfo` is however helpful for data to see for everybody.

Comment: And `catchfile` is great, in my example I used `\immediate\write18{git log -1 --format="\@percentchar H" > currentVersionLong}` and then `\IfFileExists{currentVersionLong}{\CatchFileDef{\githashlong}{currentVersionLong}{}}{\newcommand{\githashlong}{No commit info}}` to store everything in `\githashlong` and then use it for the XMP and PDF data.

Comment: This answer, although accepted is not really true. The info dictionary is shown when present. However, when *only* XMP is present XMP is shown. And info dictionary is deprecated. It's better to use XMP only.

Comment: @tanGIS and do you know a way to suppress the info dictionary completly with pdftex?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer `hyperxmp` handles this automatically unless you set `keeppdfinfo`. DocumentInfo is never suppressed completely. `CreationDate` and `ModDate` should always be present there. The big difference is that `XMP` can handle tags in different languages and lists which matters for keywords and the list of used languages.

Comment: @tanGIS ah, I missunderstood you. You mean that adobe shows values from the metadata if the info dictionary don't overwrite them. Yes, one could be more precise here, I will add an edit.

Comment: Yes, from the XMP metadata. Info Dictionary is metadata as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{hyperxmp}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{gitver}

\title{The title}
\author{The author}

\hypersetup{%
   pdfcopyright={\textcopyright\ 2020 by the publisher},
   pdfversionid=\gitVer,
   pdflicenseurl={https://tex.stackexchange.com}
}

\begin{document}
    Just an empty document
\end{document}
```

And you see your data under «additional metadata»:
[image: Acrobat screenshot file properties]
[image: Acrobat screenshot advanced metadata]

Since I have no git repository the value is «unknown».